# Get the event date clicked in Angular 7 fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using FullCalendar in my angular 7 application, i have added multiple events on dates, which comes from backend logic.
I have been able to get the date on day click event, but i can't seem to get the date on the eventclick method.
I've been trying to get the date of an event in full calendar.

Assume the date is loaded on the events property of fullcalendar.

> .html file

```
<full-calendar dateClick="dateClick($event)" eventClick="eventClick($event)">
```

> .ts file

```
eventClick(model){
console.log(model);
}
```

But this does not give me the date of the event which was clicked.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(model.event.start, model.event.end);` should give you the start and end dates of the clicked event. You just need to drill into the object to get the correct properties. The structure of the object supplied to the callback is documented at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick . It's a bit unclear what your issue is, to be honest. Even just `console.log(model);` would show you the dates, if you expand the logged object enough.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<full-calendar dateClick="dateClick($event)" (click)="eventClick($event)">
```

Try with click parentheses

Here is the ts to try

```
eventClick(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Plochie, actually it is already in paranthesis, forgot to type that in the question, i need both (dateClick) and (eventClick) methods, as i'm using both of those seperately.

Comment: Hi @Hitech sorry it's the same as you mentioned, just forgot to add it in the question

Comment: @Hitech can you show me how to use (click)="eventClick($event)" in .ts file to get the date?